# "fleece" vs. "wool"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say in English

"Wollie **had grown so much fleece** that he didn't even look like a sheep. Mr Amstrong decided **to cut his fleece** later."

?

As far as I know, fleece is processed wool. So, is it okay to say that a sheep grew a lot of fleece? And is it okay to say that somebody was going to cut fleece from a sheep meaning the act of shearing?

This sentence was in a senior-high school entrance exam in one country in Asia.

Comment: "As far as I know" - did you check any dictionaries for the meaning of 'fleece'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Yes, I did. I checked Webster. But it doesn't answer those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wool grows from the skin of sheep. This coating or covering of wool is called the sheep's 'fleece'. It can be cut ('sheared') off and the removed wool can also be called a 'fleece'. It is correct to use the word 'fleece' for both.

[image]

Fleece (noun) has two main meanings. The first of these below is the one used in your quoted text:

> the thick covering of wool on an animal, especially a sheep,
>
> this covering used to make a piece of clothing:

[Fleece (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fleece)

Comment: So, I still don't get it, is it okay to say "to cut the fleece" or not? Neither Webster, nor your link answers that.

Comment: I am a bit confused by "thick covering of wool on an animal, especially a sheep". I have never seen that on a sheep. I've seen owners putting some wool covering on their pets in the winter, but never on a sheep. I don't quite understand why a sheep would need that covering when it already protected by its own wool.

Comment: @brilliant - I have added a picture showing a "thick covering of wool on a sheep". A 'covering' does not have to be an added thing. I have a thick covering of hair on my head (I am glad to say, at my age). That does not mean I am wearing a hat made of hair. If I do not shave regularly I will grow a covering of hair on my upper lip, cheeks, and chin.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you.

Comment: The usual word for 'cutting off a sheep's fleece' is **shearing** the sheep.

Comment: @KateBunting - but 'cut' (for the OP's benefit) is not wrong, just less usual than 'shear'.